# What the link between radical(root) and its meaning in chemistry inside etymology

Tags: nomenclature, etymology

All i know `radical` mean `root` and when i heard root all what i think about is the root in plant so what the link?

Why they chose that word?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say a group of atoms is linked to a radical?

Comment: @SafdarFaisal Im sorry about my (not clear question-i edit it) i was mean root is thing i can found in plant so why they use it in chemistry? And what the link?

Comment: The history is explained very well, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_theory. Read it and modify the query if you still do not understand.

Comment: @AChem That what i found : "A radical was identified as the root base of certain acids (The Latin word "radix" meaning "root"). The combination of a radical with oxygen would result in an acid. " so... Is that the answer? If yes so that all the radicals is just can make acid with oxygen or..?(maybe i still dont understand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Words in any language can have one etymology but different senses and meanings.  Yes, radix means plant roots but radical in chemistry and mathematics have nothing to do with plant roots. They have completely different meanings. Now one can ask why mathematicians call something radical? The square root sign is basically an "r" of the mathematical radical. Plant roots have only a figurative connotation with the radical as something which is the "basis". A radical person sticks to closely to the original roots of his/her idealogy (often used in a negative sense).

In a chemical usage, one can add a little bit more to the above answer, radical or radicle (in even  older books) simply meant:

> An atom or group of atoms regarded as a (or the) primary constituent
> of a compound or class of compounds, remaining unaltered during
> chemical reactions in which other constituents are added or removed.
> Now more widely: an atom or group of atoms which behaves as a unit and
> is regarded as a distinct entity (*OED* entry)

Suppose a chemist analyzes sulfuric acid $\ce{H2SO4}$ in the 17-18th century. He finds that sulfur and oxygen ratio is 1:4 by mass. Next he add a base, sodium hydroxide to neutralize the acid, and after evaporation he isolates the salt. The salt is analyzed and it is also found the contain sulfur and oxygen ratio of 1:4. For that ancient chemist, $\ce{SO4}$ is a *sulfate radical*. *It is a group of atom that is behaving as a unit* in a chemical reaction. Forget about charges on sulfate, that did not exist when "radicals" were discussed

Looks at a snippet from 1858 book, that shows organic radicals= group of atoms that behave as a unit.
[image]

The above answer by Nilay shows more modern meaning of radicals.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the text from the [Wikipedia article of Radicals:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_(chemistry)#History_and_nomenclature)

> The term radical was already in use when the now obsolete radical theory was developed. Louis-Bernard Guyton de Morveau introduced the phrase "radical" in 1785 and the phrase was employed by Antoine Lavoisier in 1789 in his Traité Élémentaire de Chimie. A radical was then identified as the root base of certain acids (the Latin word "radix" meaning "root").

At that time, chemists considered "radical" as the "free element" of the acid entity. For e.g. sulfur for sulfuric acid etc. He even considered that the word before acid is the radical like "acetic" for acetic acid, "muriatic" for muriatic acid (hydrochloric acid).

> When Lavoiser dealt with the nature of acids, he assumed them to be oxygenated substances, i.e. oxygen combined with an entity which he chose to name a radical. According to his concept, the radical might be a single element in the case of the inorganic acids (sulphur in sulphuric and sulphurous acids, phosphorus in phosphoric and phosphoraus acids, carbon in carbonic acid, the "radical muriatique" in muriatic acid, the "radical boracique" in boric acid), or it might be some stable combination of carbon and hydrogen in the various organic acids. The designation of an element as a radical quickly passed out of favour, particularly after Davy demonstrated that oxygen is not an essential part of an acid.

Then as both organic and inorganic chemistry grew, chemists were identifying more and more "free" species. Like the first organic "radical" identified was the triphenylmethyl radical, $\ce{(C6H5)3C•}$ by Moses Gomberg in 1900 which abolished the idea that "radicals" shouldn't be the elemental species but rather the "free" species originating (rooting) from an established/stable species.

The meaning of "radical" has evolved through phases and now in modern chemistry, radicals are more than just "roots".

**References**:

1. THE HISTORY OF FREE RADICALS AND MOSES GOMBERG'S CONTRIBUTIONS, AARON J. IHDE, Chemistry Department, University of Wisconsin,
   Madison, Wisconsin 53706, U.S.A.
2. Walton, J. C., Nonhebel, D. C. (**1974**). Free-Radical Chemistry: Structure and Mechanism. Kiribati: Cambridge University Press.

Comment: @NilayGhosh thank you for your answer. Can you help me if i understand well? First- what i understand is that they use radical which mean root from latin word radix as something essential like in plant the root is something essential. Second - the chemist considered the radical is free element because its can react fast or its have the ability to react.  Third- i couldnt understand that: *by Moses Gomberg in 1900 which abolished the idea that "radicals" shouldn't be the elemental species but rather the "free" species originating (rooting) from an established/stable species. * - Plz help

Comment: @Pcp115 1. Yes. But it essentially doesn't have to be a plant. Root of anything is radical. 2. No. They initially thought that the acids came from free element like sulfuric acid came from sulfur. So, they considered sulfur as the radical. Even a "stable" species containing hydrogen and carbon reacting with oxygen to give acid were considered as radical. These assumptions were later proved wrong. 3. When Gomberg identified "triphenylmethyl radical", it abolished the idea that radicals are not free elements nor stable species rather free species from a stable species- triphenylmethane